# MacOs "alt+key" combination (e.g. \ @) on Centos VirtualBox not working

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard, cloudera-quickstart-vm, teamviewer

I am having a probably trivial issue with the **Cloudera Quickstart** virtual machine. I tried many things out, but I don't manage to make it work. So, first, I installed the **Virtualbox** image on a Windows workstation which has a German standard (qwertz) keyboard. 
In the virtual machine, which runs a Linux Centos, I set the German keyboard and everything works fine. Now, as the workstation is in my office, I installed **TeamViewer**, in order to connect from my MacBook from home. And here it comes the issue that struggles me.

The MacBook has a German keyboard and all the keys, which do not require the **alt** combination works fine. If I need, for example @ (alt+L) or \ (alt+shift+7), or anything that requires the alt combination, nothing appears on the Centos (in the Windows workstation it would correctly appear!). Could you imagine to code without \ ~ @ ??

I tried also to install a German(Mac) keyboard and also a screen keyboard (florence) in the Centos and they also do not work properly. Is it a TeamViewer issue or a VirtualBox issue? How can I solve it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that is a Virtualbox issue, that takes the keyboard configuration of the host in which is installed, in this case Windows 10. I could not find a simple way changing the keyboard setting in the Centos machine run via the Mac Os in TeamViewer to make it work. So, as workaround, I opted for using Docker Cloudera Quickstart rather than the VM. And everything works fine and can happily type all the @~|\ that I need.